# Concatenate HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, url

I'm building my output text looping a JSON object using JavaScript.  Everything is working fine until I come to the part where I need to add an ID number to an image URL.  My images are stored in a database and I am using an ASHX handler to load the image however what I end up with is not exactly what I need.

My code that I need to end up with is `~/ImageHandler.ashx?id=35`
 
but what I get is `~/ImageHandler.ashx?id='35'`.  Single quotes around the ID.

I know it is the syntax of `"` and `""`.

What I have tried is

```
myOutput += "<img src ='~/ImageHandler.ashx?id='"  + ID  + class='person-image'></img>"
```

and every combination that does not work.

If I remember correctly I need some combination of triple single quote or double quotes something or some combination of the both. `ID` is an integer that is being read from a JSON object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us how you're generating the URL.

Comment: "Show me the code" -- Linus Torvalds

Comment: `var handler = "~/ImageHandler.ashx?id=" + jsonObj.ID`

Comment: let try this myOutput += "<img src ='~/ImageHandler.ashx?id='" + d[i].memberID  +  " class='person-image'></img>"

Comment: Sorry- My code was parsed out from the original post

Comment: Dude, you're adding the quote marks yourself. Look at `id='"`. Just remove them. `"<img src='~/ImageHandler.ashx?id=" + ID + " class='person-image' />"`

Comment: You would still need the closing single quote after ID: `"<img src='~/ImageHandler.ashx?id=" + ID + "' class='person-image' />"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add double quotes using the escape character `\`

```
myOutput += "<img src=\"~/ImageHandler.ashx?id="  + ID  + "\" class=\"person-image\"></img>"
```

This will append

```
<img src="~/ImageHandler.ashx?id=35" class="person-image"></img>
```

Comment: Better remove the enclosing double quotes from "This will append" as they will not be appended to the string.

Comment: Good point, edited